# How to save the change for pandas dataframe after iterating by row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I create a simple function to replace a certain column in df by row:

```
def replace(df):
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row['ALARM_TEXT'] = row['ALARM_TEXT'].replace('\'','')
return df
```

But the input df has not been changed after I call the function. Is there something wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

We usually do

```
 df['ALARM_TEXT'] = df['ALARM_TEXT'].str.replace('\'','')
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'